Using MPI via MPICH, only rank 0 shows up, regardless of the multiple ranks input
I have a "working" version of MPI, installed via MPICH. For context, I'm running this on Ubuntu 24.04.
My problem is that if I take a simple hello.cpp program, like this:
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  std::cout << "Hello from processor " << world_rank;
  std::cout << " out of " << world_size << " processors." << std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

and compile and run it like so:
mpicxx.mpich hello.cpp
mpirun.mpich -np 4 ./a.out

It only shows a single rank in a serial implementation, namely:
Hello from processor 0 out of 1 processors.
Hello from processor 0 out of 1 processors.
Hello from processor 0 out of 1 processors.
Hello from processor 0 out of 1 processors.

For context, I do not have an OpenMPI implementation installed to convolute the paths. However, I do have the Intel opeapi implementation, though I need to explicitly set its variables to use its version of compiler. For context, if I compile and run via the Intel compiler, it works as expected, as in
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
mpiicpx hello.cpp
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out

It outputs the following expected outcome:
Hello from processor 1 out of 4 processors.
Hello from processor 2 out of 4 processors.
Hello from processor 3 out of 4 processors.
Hello from processor 0 out of 4 processors.

Also, for completeness' sake, here's what I get when I run the following:

mpicxx.mpich --version

g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


which mpicxx.mpich

/usr/bin/mpicxx.mpich


mpirun.mpich --version

HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 4.2.0
    Release Date:                            Fri Feb  9 12:29:21 CST 2024
    CC:                              gcc -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3 -g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=/usr/src/mpich-4.2.0-5build3 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -Wl,-z,relro 
    Configure options:                       '--with-hwloc-prefix=/usr' '--with-device=ch4:ucx' 'FFLAGS=-O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=/usr/src/mpich-4.2.0-5build3 -fallow-invalid-boz -fallow-argument-mismatch' '--prefix=/usr' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fcf-protection -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mpich-C3oteG/mpich-4.2.0=/usr/src/mpich-4.2.0-5build3' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=3'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Demux engines available:                 poll select


ldd ./a.out (when compiled via mpicxx.mpich)

    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcbd7c5000)
    libmpich.so.12 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12 (0x00007a7172c00000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007a7172800000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007a7172400000)
    libhwloc.so.15 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.15 (0x00007a71754a1000)
    libpmix.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpmix.so.2 (0x00007a7172000000)
    libucp.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucp.so.0 (0x00007a7172a9d000)
    libucs.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0 (0x00007a7175439000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007a717551a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007a7175350000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007a71727d3000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007a71727a0000)
    libmunge.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmunge.so.2 (0x00007a7175346000)
    libevent_core-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core-2.1.so.7 (0x00007a717276b000)
    libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7 (0x00007a7172a98000)
    libuct.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuct.so.0 (0x00007a7172725000)
    libucm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucm.so.0 (0x00007a7172708000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007a7172a8b000)

Any help is much appreciated. I hope this is also helpful for someone else stuck in a similar situation, since most of the similar questions in SO seem to converge to the same problem: a mixed OpenMPI and MPICH installation. Which, as far as I can tell, is not the problem here?
Thanks!

@GillesGouaillardet So it's a bug then. Yes, I guess the problem is pretty much similar. Thanks man :)

this is more of a packaging issue imho, but yeah, you did nothing wrong here.

Since you ran into this issue, you could comment here to raise awareness: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpich/+bug/2072338

@Joachim done :)
